# filter list Items REST API

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, rest

I have a lits sharepoint which have an user item.I need get the items filtering by user like this :

```
http://win-f898lhd0rn9//_api/web/lists/getbytitle('BudgetConcerneLD')/items?$filter=IPS_Personne eq '1'
```

but it doesnt geve any information : 
I tried :

```
http://win-f898lhd0rn9//_api/web/lists/getbytitle('BudgetConcerneLD')/items?$filter=IPS_PersonneId eq '1'
```

I show an exception.

When i uset REST client this the json object :

```
    <d:IPS_PersonneId m:type="Collection(Edm.Int32)">
<d:element>2</d:element>
</d:IPS_PersonneId>
<d:IPS_BudgetAffect_x00e9_>500</d:IPS_BudgetAffect_x00e9_>
```

So what is the exact query ?

Comment: Don't forget to select Amal's answer! :-) Otherwise it looks like you question is still unsolved and it continues to appear on the main page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$expand` as below

`http://win-f898lhd0rn9//_api/web/lists/getbytitle('BudgetConcerneLD')/items?&expand=IPS_Personne&$filter=IPS_Personne/Id eq 1`

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer looks good. Mind the filters for integer :

```
Wrong      IPS_PersonneId eq '1'
Instead    IPS_PersonneId eq 1
```

I also sometimes have problem with combining filters and expand, in order to expand, test both

```
Test this          AuthorId
But also this      Author/ID
```

I always get confused with that ;-)